# How do I prevent this infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, infinite-loop

I need to pass foo in the arguments of useEffect so that it can use the existing array values. So I set the new values in this array but when I went to set the value, it'll call f() function again from the userEffect. How do I get out this infinit loop?

Imaginary code example goes something like this:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState<MyType>(...);

const f = () => {
    const baa = {...foo};
    for(...) {
        foo.arr[x] = y;
    }
    setFoo(foo);
}

useEffect(() => {
    f();
    g();
    // ...
}, [foo]);
```

Comment: Simple... don't change state in effect hooks that list that state as a dependency.

Comment: Your code is too obfuscated to properly explain what you're trying to do and why. Please [edit] your question with a more concrete example and explain what it is you're after

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript functions have access to variables in the scope above them, so you don't need to pass foo as an argument to any of these functions.

Passing foo as an agument in useEffect means that we call useEffect every time foo changes. This is what is causing your infinite loop and it doesn't seem like you want to call this every time foo changes so I would leave it out

Answer (score 0):

Effect hooks run whenever their dependencies are initialised or changed. Altering a state dependency in the hook means you end up in an infinite loop.

I suspect you want some sort of computed value derived from `foo`. For this, there's the [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) which will compute the new value every time its dependencies change.

```js
const fooWithBenefits = useMemo(
  () => ({
    ...foo,
    arr: [...foo.arr.slice(0, x), y, ...foo.arr.slice(x + 1)],
  }),
  [foo]
);
```

You'd then use `fooWithBenefits` in your component instead of `foo`.